# .htaccess - rewrite of dynamic links (according to the value of variable)

Tags: .htaccess, url

I have set of links like for example:

```
samplefile.php?post=Test 1
samplefile.php?post=Test 2
...
samplefile.php?post=Test 14
...
```

I would like to rewrite or redirect it respectively to: (I need both options for 2 separate cases)

```
samplefile-Test-1.php and (samplefileTest1.php)
samplefile-Test2.php and (samplefileTest2.php)
...
samplefile-Test-14.php and (samplefileTest14.php)
...
```

So that require replacing empty space with '-', or trimming empty space at all.
Is it possible to achieve what I want?
If yes how do I do this?
Thank you very much for your help in advance!

UPDATE: I can do this, but that's not good enough, hoping to do better (:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^post=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^samplefile\.php$ http://www.exampledomain.com/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Do you already have some rewrite rules? If yes, then show them in question.

Comment: @anubhava Don't relly have much.Thats why I ask. For now i only could redirect all these files to one common link, that's ok but ideally i would like to achive what I ask for. I updeted the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these 2 distinct set of rules:

For `samplefile-Test-1.php, samplefile-Test-2.php .. samplefile-Test-3.php`

```
# first strip query string and redirect /samplefile.php?post=Test 1 to
# /samplefile-Test 1.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^post=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(samplefile)\.php/?$ /$1-%1.php? [NC,L,NE,R=302]

# if URL only has white-spaces in the middle then redirect to
# /testfile-Test-1.php
RewriteRule ^samplefile(-\S*)\s+(\S*\.php)$ /testfile$1-$2 [L,NE,R=302]

# if URL has white spaces at multiple places then replace whitespace by hyphen
# and loop the rule
RewriteRule ^(samplefile-\S*)\s+(\S+\s+.*\.php)$ /$1-$2 [N,NC,DPI]
```

For `samplefileTest1.php, samplefileTest2.php .. samplefileTest14.php`

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^post=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(samplefile)\.php/?$ /$1%1.php? [NC,L,NE,R]

RewriteRule ^samplefile(\S*)\s+(\S*\.php)$ /testfile$1$2 [L,NE,NC,R=302]
RewriteRule ^(samplefile\S*)\s+(\S+\s+.*\.php)$ /$1$2 [N,NC,DPI]
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you very much @anubhavaI tested it works perfectly. Could you be so kind to give me a brief explanation. While testing new necessity arise. I was trying to work it out without bothering but I guess I have a long way to understand redirections at higher level.  What if want to change the name of the final file to (testfile-Test-1.php or testfileTest1.php) ? Accounting the starting point stays the same ... samplefile.php?post=Test 1

Comment: I've modified the answer for `/testfile-Test-1.php` and added some comments.

Comment: thank you, anubhava  do not want to be too pushy but cound you consider to advice me on redirecting to diiferent file name, or should i create seperate question

Comment: Actually I've already changed the rule above `RewriteRule ^samplefile(-\S*)\s+(\S*\.php)$ /testfile$1-$2 [L,NE,R=302]` to redirect to a different filename.

Comment: ups, sorry see it now, what about "   RewriteRule ^(samplefile-\S*)\s+(\S+\s+.*\.php)$ /$1-$2 [N,NC,DPI]  " doesn't need to be altered with "  /testfile$1-$2  " ?

Comment: No, that doesn't need to be changed as we change filename only once at the time of redirection with `R` flag.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128257/discussion-between-nita-and-anubhava).